# swift 3 firebase snapshot if value equal to ... fetch

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, snapshot

[image]

I'm Trying to check if the rooms's value 'Owner' equals to the current user id if so then fetch all data including the key value and continue checking other children of 'rooms'

I was trying, but I fail finding the solution though it might seem easy so please help me with your suggestions or ideas. My code so far :

```
          Database.database().reference().child("rooms").queryOrdered(byChild: "Owner").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

      let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

        if !snapshot.exists() {
            print("No data found")
            return
        }

        var rooms = snapshot.value as! [String:AnyObject]
        let roomKeys = Array(rooms.keys)

        for roomKey in roomKeys  {

            guard

                let value = rooms[roomKey] as? [String:AnyObject]

                else
            {
                continue
            }

            let title = value["title"] as? String
            let description = value["description"] as? String
            let roomPictureUrl = value["Room Picture"] as? String
            let longitude = value["Longtitude"] as? String
            let latitude = value["Latitude"] as? String
            let dateFrom = value["Date From"] as? String
            let dateTo = value["Date To"] as? String
            let owner = value["Owner"] as? String

            let myRooms = Room(roomID: roomKey,title: title!, description: description!, roomPicutreURL: roomPictureUrl!, longitude: longitude!, latitude: latitude!, dateFrom: dateFrom!, dateTo: dateTo!, owner: owner!)

            self.rooms.append(myRooms)
            self.tableView.reloadData()

            print(snapshot.value)

        }
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the value in your query:

```
Database.database().reference()
  .child("rooms")
  .queryOrdered(byChild: "Owner")
  .queryEqual(toValue: "STbz...")
  .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
```

See for this and more query operators, the [documentation on filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#filtering_data).

Answer (score 1):

Mark:- Swift 5

```
Database.database().reference().child("user")
        .queryOrdered(byChild: "UserPhoneNumber") //in which column you want to find
        .queryEqual(toValue: "Your phone number or any column value")
        .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if snapshot.childrenCount > 0
            {
                if let snapShot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
                    //MARK:- User Exist in database
                    for snap in snapShot{
                        //MARK:- User auto id for exist user
                        print(snap.key) 
                        break
                    }
                }

            }
            else if snapshot.childrenCount == 0
            {
                //MARK:- User not exist no data found
            }
    })
```